# elasticsearch - Document contained within search term

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index as follows:

```
"_source": {
  "iD": "378",
  "containsTerms": [
    {
      "containsTerm": "search term to match"
    },
    {
      "containsTerm": "another search term to match"
    },
    {
      "containsTerm": "etcetera"
    }
  ],
  "startdate": "2022-09-08T14:07:00",
  "enddate": "2022-09-30T14:07:00"
}
```

And its mapping is:

```
"mappings":{
   "properties":{
      "containsTerms":{
         "properties":{
            "containsTerm":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "enddate":{
         "type":"date"
      },
      "startdate":{
         "type":"date"
      }
   }
}
```

The following query running on the index works as expected:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "containsTerms.containsTerm":{
                     "query":"search term to match"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "startdate":{
                     "lte":"2022-09-22T14:43:38"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "enddate":{
                     "gte":"2022-09-22T15:43:38"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

elasticsearch returns the documents on all partial search phrases e.g.

- search
- search term
- search term to
- search term to match

and also on larger phrases e.g.

- search term to match blah blah blah

so far so good.

However, the requirement is that the document is only returned on an exact match. Changing the query to use keyword

```
{
  "match":{
    "containsTerms.containsTerm.keyword":{
      "query":"search term to match"
    }
  }
}
```

ensures that only a search for 'search term to match' will return the document. This works fine.

***However***... the requirement is to return a document with an *exact* match on the term contained within a larger phrase.

For instance:

"blah blah **search term to match** blah blah" should return the document, whereas "blah blah **search term to** blah blah" should not.

It is almost as if, rather than returning results where the search term is contained within the document, we should be returning results where the document is contained within the search term.

I am not sure whether this is even possible, or what type of query to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match_phrase` type of query which will match phrase into large text.

> "blah blah **search term to match** blah blah" should return the document,
> whereas "blah blah **search term to** blah blah" should not.

below query will cover your above usecase.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "containsTerms.containsTerm": "search term to match"
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you want to get entire document when query match to atlest one element of your `containsTerms` object.

Comment: That doesn't satisfy the usecase of matching "blah blah search term to match blah blah". Sorry

Comment: do you want to get document if atleast your query match to one element of `containsTerms` object or do you want to get only `containsTerm` which is matching with your query inside `containsTerms` object

Comment: it should match the exact phrase on any of the containsTerms, even if the posted search term contains more text than the containTerm, but it should be an exact match to the contain term

Comment: As per my understanding, `match_phrase` will do same thing. If you have two seperate document, first one is `blah blah search term to match blah blah` and second is `blah blah search term to blah blah` and if you are searching `search term to match` then it will return only first document and not second document.

Comment: you have it the wrong way around. the indexed document will have 'search term to match' whilst the posted search may contain 'blah blah search term to match blah blah'. It should match the document because the posted search contains the exact phrase 'search term to match' to match the document, but a posted search of 'blah blah search term to blah blah' wouldn't match because the exact term 'search term to match' isn't within the posted search string.

Comment: ahh got it. Let me check and update my answer.